# Marlin RAMPS 1.4 reboot problem while printing via SD card

Tags: marlin, arduino, ramps

I have a custom 3D printer with RAMPS 1.4 and Arduino Mega 2560 (clone). I installed Marlin 2.0.7.2 firmware and I tested all the motion and heating parts individually and all of them work fine.
Also, I activated SDSUPPORT and the printer can read my .gcode files from the SD card. When I try to print a 20 mm calibration cube by using an SD card, starting G-code works fine (printer goes home point) at the time of reading G-code from SD card, LCD goes weird and after 2 seconds printer reboots itself.

For now I can't print via USB because of distance and cable issues, can you give any suggestion to handle this?

Comment: @agarza - Thank you for all of the recent top quality edits. Keep up the good work. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: Hi M.SEL! Does it reboot always at the same point - or rather randomly? I wonder if it still could be bug or misconfiguration in firmware or on hardware level (activating board reset, etc.) or some more complicated problem, like floating voltage or some short/dry joint activated by vibration... Doe the same print work OK when executed from serial terminal, or you could never try even once?

Comment: @octopus8 hi . it seems it reboots always at  the same point , as if it cant read G-codes from SD card properly.i tried another SD card but same problem occured . i couldnt try serial terminal yet

Comment: Try then to narrow down to **specific command or command sequence**. I.e. execute single lines, but better avoid Marlin's "stop" routine... so I propose following: from the original G-code file, generate more *.gcode files, containing: only 1st line, only first 2 lines, only first 3 lines, only first 4 lines, etc. Then check if they will be properly. Or if not at least one will execute properly, then maybe SD reader or connection is an issue (just compare to [https://reprap.org/wiki/Melzi](https://reprap.org/wiki/Melzi), the 3rd bullet from the bottom)...

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find a fix to it?

Comment: @EstebanYañez yes , i  removed bootscreens and other needless configs that consumes progmem , i think problem is related with memory , you can also try different arduino mega board or use original one